# Can I eliminate the pump in my septic system?

Tags: septic

I have a pressurized septic system with the second tank and a pump, and the pump keeps tripping the breaker and setting off the alarm even though I've put new plugs on it and replaced the breaker. What I would like to know is, could I just eliminate the pump and let the tank drain by itself out to the drain field? Why do I need the pump?

Comment: Can you show us a photo of the pump's nameplate, or even give us a model number on it?  Also, is this breaker a standard breaker, or a GFCI or AFCI (look for a TEST button)?

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't eliminate the pump. The drain field is higher than the septic tank.

If you have a mound system (elevated drainfield) or a pressurized sewer system, then the pump has to lift the effluent (outflow from the septic tank) up to the drain field level or pump against the pressure of a pressurized utility system.

If you eliminate the pump then sewage will eventually back up into your house. Yuck!

If the pump keeps tripping the breaker and you have replaced the breaker then the pump is probably malfunctioning and needs repair or replacement.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The pump is bad; when they get old, they start pulling more amps and this is probably why your breaker is tripping. You could also have a faulty wiring so be very careful taking the old pump out; if the water is steaming when you open the tank, the water is being heated by a bad motor and there is also a good chance it is grounding in the water as well. You should use extreme caution.